# Returning Total Number of Messages Sent Via Slack API

Tags: slack-api, slack

Looking for a way to return the total number of messages sent by a team via the Slack API.  Browsing the documentation I have not come across a method to do this.  Was curious if anyone has a found a way to do something similar.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to iterate over all channels, groups and users. For a given channel, the [`search.messages`](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages) endoint contains the info you need. For instance, using the python Slacker package, we can count the number of messages in `@general`:

```
>>> import slacker
>>> token = "yourtoken"
>>> api = slacker.BaseAPI(token)
>>> api.get("search.messages", params={"query": "in:general"}).body["messages"]["total"]
19601
```

(I leave it to you to iterate over all channels and groups)

Comment: Please note that the max count value is 1000 and the max page value is 100 for this method.

Comment: `count` is the "number of items to return per page" and `page` is "page number of results to return". In your question you ask for the number of messages, not the complete list of all messages. As you can see in my example, obtained from a real Slack channel, these two parameters do not affect how the number of messages is obtained.

Answer (score 1):

There is not API method that provides that information directly, so you will need to calculate that information by iterating of all existing channels.

Basic outline:

1. Get list of all channels with [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list)
2. Get all messages for a channel with
   [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history). You can directly specify the time period you are interested in with the `latest` and `oldest` properties
3. Sum the counts per channel to get the total

Note that due to Slack's security architecture you will not have access to all private and direct messaging channels. To also get those conversations you will need to collect a token from each of your users and then use those token to get access to everything.